# Unknown notation for a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand a text about the dualizing sheaf which is yet very advanced for me. In the text appears a notation which I don't know and I was unfortunately not successful in finding it myself in books.

Let $C$ be a projective curve and $U\subset C$ an open, $S:=C\setminus U$.

What is the definition of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-nS)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Thanks in advance for all hints.

Comment: Here $S$ is a divisor, $nS$ is also a divisor. $\mathcal O(-nS)$  is the dual of the line bundle corresponding to the divisor $nS.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! With "divisor" you mean "Weil-divisor" and the codimension of $S$ is necessarily 1?

Comment: codim $S=1.$ because it's a proper closed subset of $C$ and hence dim $S <$ dim $C.$

Comment: @Cla: the claim in your comment above is not right. Suppose $S$ is a divisor of degree $s$. If $C$ is embedded with degree $d$, then the line bundle $O(1)$ has degree $d$. So $O(S) \otimes O(k)$ has degree $s+kd$. On the other hand $O(kS)$ has degree $ks$.

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh, you are right. I wanted to suggest him/her another way to look at that, namely the twisting by an ample line bundle..but of course the choice of an ample class involves some precaution. Sorry if this will cause confusion.

Comment: @Cla: it _will_ cause confusion if you don't delete your comment. Twisting by ample line bundles is not relevant here.